# Is there any possible way to programatically rate an android app without entering google play

Tags: java, android, google-play

Is there any possible way to rate an android app without entering the play store?? I am thinking of creating a java application that can give a rating instantly for a particular app,so that the user only need to input the google account details in the java application.

Comment: No. that would be cheating :D

Comment: I suppose that rating would be 5 and that 'particular app' would be your own?

Comment: It would only be cheating if that application would try to cheat. You should look at the user reviews of apps for blind and low vision users. If you write an app for the blind, I guess you should just resign yourself to only have one star ratings because your blind and low vision users have no idea how to give you a positive star rating (despite most of them writing positive reviews).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk GPlay has not accesibility for blind people?

Comment: @jonathanrz, Android itself has accessibility features for blind people, so I assume the Google Play Store does as well. Also, this would explain why blind users can leave reviews. It's just that this accessibility feature doesn't seem to work for changing the number of stars (or that it is too difficult to use, because blind users do leave one star reviews even though their written reviews can be super positive).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk well, then the solution is to call Google and aks them to correct that. It is a big fail for google play not being totally accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but you may use this :  if something click on button rate me :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
try {
    context.startActivity(goToMarket);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    UtilityClass.showAlertDialog(context, ERROR, "Couldn't launch the market", null, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible and directly in violation of play store terms anyway